# How to transfer identity and other user information between idp adapters in pingfederate?

Tags: saml, pingfederate, two-factor-authentication

I am creating a custom adapter in  pingfederate in-between  an LDAP Adapter and a pingID  adapter for customising the two factor authentication and session management. so I want to get inputs from the first adapter,specifically the username(SAML-- SAML_SUBJECT) and pass some information to the ping ID adapter. so here I want to get communicated between adapters. I didn't found any documentation for this?  any helping hands here? :(

Comment: What version of PingFederate are you using?

Comment: Hi Andrew,
My pingFederate version is 7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in your version is via cookies and javascript using a method similar to [this](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA3400000008SVoCAM). Version 8 of PingFed supports this OOTB.